# What's the proper way to get a string slice from a Rc<RefCell<String>>?

Tags: rust

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

fn main() {
    let wrapped_string = Rc::from(RefCell::from(String::from("hello there my majesty")));
    let partial: str = wrapped_string.borrow()[7..18];
}
```

gives the error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
5 |     let partial: str = wrapped_string.borrow()[7..18];
  |         ^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `str`
  = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
  = help: unsized locals are gated as an unstable feature
help: consider borrowing here
  |
5 |     let partial: str = &wrapped_string.borrow()[7..18];
  |                        ^
```

Comment: I encourage you to read the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help you understand what the problem. Please use the message from running the compiler directly (e.g. `cargo build`), not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: If the intention is to get a string slice, why is `partial` annotated with `str`? That tells the compiler you want an owned `str`. It should be annotated with `&str`, which results in a more direct error message (even though the message with the original code gives plenty of details). This amounts to no more than a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```rust
let partial: str = wrapped_string.borrow()[7..18];
```

to

```
let partial: &str = &wrapped_string.borrow()[7..18];
```